# promotion artifact repository from Snapshot to Release in Nexus

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus

I am trying to promote artifact repository from Snapshot to Release in Nexus using Single artifact uploader in Jenkins . But this is not working for me.
Getting error like :

> Could not resolve artifact: Could not find artifact
>   Snapshots.net.iin:snapshots:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in stagingrepo.

And I check from [configuring the staging suite](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager2/staging-releases/configuring-the-staging-suite) and got to know that Staging is part of the Nexus Repository Manager Pro. 
I am using Nexus version - Nexus Repository Manager OSS 2.14.8-01.

I wanted to promote these snapshot artifacts to Release .So what's the best way to take this forward?

Comment: You can't promote a SNAPSHOT version to become a release. You need to build it accordingly...Apart from that do you have a Nexus pro version running?

Comment: ok . No I have Nexus Repository Manager OSS 2.14.8-01. Not using Nexus pro.

Comment: So If you are using OSS version you have no promotion...at all....

Comment: Ok . Thanks khmarbaise.

Comment: Just checking artifact-promotion plugin in Jenkins also not working in case I am using Nexus OSS version . Am I right ?

Comment: Pro Nexus has a special feature to promote artifacts. In Pro and OSS, you can have multiple repos and copy (or move) artifacts from one to the next in the promotion order by downloading from one repo and uploading to the next one. This is what the Jenkins promotion plugin does for freestyle jobs. Typically you use the exact same version number on the artifact as you promote but you can't put artifacts with SNAPSHOT version numbers in a release repo so the promotion doesn't work.

Comment: The usual way to change from SNAPSHOT to release is by changing the version tag in the pom (or the build.gradle) and rebuilding once testing with snapshots determines its ready for release. Then you rerun the build (mvn, gradle) and create a new artifact that is not a snapshot. (This is part of the problem with snapshots that you don't have exactly the same artifact that you tested if you rebuild. A plugin version might change and mess up the build.)